# Adding transformations to String using Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

How can I get the 2nd string from the first using Angular 2 ?

My first string

> whatIWantToShowCorrectly

My second string

> What I want to show correctly

[I've found that I can transform upperCase caracters to lowerCase ones using LowerCasePipe]

Is there a way to add spaces to my string without going through the creation of a function?

Comment: You might want to look at regular expression. Your problem has nothing to do with Angular2. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions. You can create a custom pipe https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html to make the functionality easily reusable.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use custom pipe like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'whitespace'})
export class WhiteSpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number) {
    return value.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
  }
}
```

And in your template:

```
{{ str | whitespace }}
```

If you want to avoid first whitespace then:

```
value.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim()
```

See also http://plnkr.co/edit/VnWHrI6aoTuooqFgj2Qa?p=preview

Comment: Yees that is what I was looking for. Thank you :D